# Magic numbers in NR spline function

Tags: spline

Can someone explain the magic numbers, which are used in the code here?

http://www.arcetri.astro.it/irlab/library/recipes/bookcpdf/c3-3.pdf

```
y2[1] = -0.5;
u[1]=(3.0/(x[2]-x[1]))*((y[2]-y[1])/(x[2]-x[1])-yp1);
```

Why -0.5 and 3.0?

```
u[i]=(6.0*u[i]/(x[i+1]-x[i-1])-sig*u[i-1])/p;
```

Why 6?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you explain which step of getting from the formulas in the text to the code is unclear?

Comment: How did they get equation 3.34?

Comment: Should we move that to mathematics.SE? I think the formula rendering for answers is not activated here, and answering would be much easier over there, apart from the question really being about deriving a formula, i.e., more suited to mathematics.SE.